# Heroku at=Error code=H10, desc="App crashed": from database import db_session, init_db, I am having that error when try to open the app from Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am building a Flask python database project with Postgress and SQAlchemy for College, And it was working ok, but suddenly stopped working in the Heroku app, Locally everything works ok.

I tried Heroku restart, also update requirements, but not successful, I am thinking that might be something related to having my database.py in the gitIgnore?

This is the Heroku log-Tail:

```
> 2022-05-27T14:32:22.907881+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last): 2022-05-27T14:32:22.907901+00:00 app[web.1]: File
> "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module> 2022-05-27T14:32:22.907973+00:00
> app[web.1]: from database import db_session, init_db
> 2022-05-27T14:32:22.907992+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'database' 2022-05-27T14:32:23.125998+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
> 2022-05-27T14:32:23.188458+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> starting to crashed 2022-05-27T15:42:22.846909+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
> State changed from crashed to starting
> 2022-05-27T15:42:26.535561+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `python app.py` 2022-05-27T15:42:27.672292+00:00 app[web.1]:
> Traceback (most recent call last): 2022-05-27T15:42:27.672313+00:00
> app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
> 2022-05-27T15:42:27.672373+00:00 app[web.1]: from database import
> db_session, init_db 2022-05-27T15:42:27.672395+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
> 2022-05-27T15:42:27.824996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2022-05-27T15:42:27.871747+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed 2022-05-27T18:59:23.224641+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
> 2022-05-27T18:59:28.161843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `python app.py` 2022-05-27T18:59:29.855235+00:00 app[web.1]:
> Traceback (most recent call last): 2022-05-27T18:59:29.855247+00:00
> app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
> 2022-05-27T18:59:29.855247+00:00 app[web.1]: from database import
> db_session, init_db 2022-05-27T18:59:29.855247+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
> 2022-05-27T18:59:30.039113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2022-05-27T18:59:30.093494+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed 2022-05-27T20:31:02.174840+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
> 2022-05-27T20:31:06.609804+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `python app.py` 2022-05-27T20:31:07.646051+00:00 app[web.1]:
> Traceback (most recent call last): 2022-05-27T20:31:07.646070+00:00
> app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
> 2022-05-27T20:31:07.646142+00:00 app[web.1]: from database import
> db_session, init_db 2022-05-27T20:31:07.646172+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
> 2022-05-27T20:31:07.799426+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2022-05-27T20:31:07.888386+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed 2022-05-27T23:41:54.790594+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
> 2022-05-27T23:41:58.691687+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `python app.py` 2022-05-27T23:42:00.313486+00:00 app[web.1]:
> Traceback (most recent call last): 2022-05-27T23:42:00.313503+00:00
> app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
> 2022-05-27T23:42:00.313573+00:00 app[web.1]: from database import
> db_session, init_db 2022-05-27T23:42:00.313591+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
> 2022-05-27T23:42:00.484426+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2022-05-27T23:42:00.588024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed 2022-05-28T05:28:31.385296+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
> 2022-05-28T05:28:36.188002+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `python app.py` 2022-05-28T05:28:37.580875+00:00 app[web.1]:
> Traceback (most recent call last): 2022-05-28T05:28:37.580896+00:00
> app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
> 2022-05-28T05:28:37.580982+00:00 app[web.1]: from database import
> db_session, init_db 2022-05-28T05:28:37.580999+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
> 2022-05-28T05:28:37.731221+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2022-05-28T05:28:37.793971+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed 2022-05-28T11:28:44.724476+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
> 2022-05-28T11:28:48.586364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `python app.py` 2022-05-28T11:28:49.680063+00:00 app[web.1]:
> Traceback (most recent call last): 2022-05-28T11:28:49.680080+00:00
> app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
> 2022-05-28T11:28:49.680147+00:00 app[web.1]: from database import
> db_session, init_db 2022-05-28T11:28:49.680166+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
> 2022-05-28T11:28:49.816846+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2022-05-28T11:28:50.000508+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed 2022-05-28T16:39:48.762632+00:00
> heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
> path="/" host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=b7ed08c7-5812-4eba-a602-64abca87f157 fwd="109.159.28.147"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-05-28T16:39:49.040476+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
> host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=ed4b01d7-1fb1-4699-bc19-f7535adc5a98 fwd="109.159.28.147"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-05-28T16:39:58.847933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> crashed to starting 2022-05-28T16:40:03.585589+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
> Starting process with command `python app.py`
> 2022-05-28T16:40:04.892504+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last): 2022-05-28T16:40:04.892523+00:00 app[web.1]: File
> "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module> 2022-05-28T16:40:04.892612+00:00
> app[web.1]: from database import db_session, init_db
> 2022-05-28T16:40:04.892633+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'database' 2022-05-28T16:40:05.072828+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
> 2022-05-28T16:40:05.299103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> starting to crashed 2022-05-28T16:40:05.307274+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
> State changed from crashed to starting
> 2022-05-28T16:40:06.167102+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
> host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=87935396-2585-487d-aa10-e41686bb059c fwd="109.159.28.147"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-05-28T16:40:09.388404+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `python app.py` 2022-05-28T16:40:10.982900+00:00 app[web.1]:
> Traceback (most recent call last): 2022-05-28T16:40:10.982914+00:00
> app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
> 2022-05-28T16:40:10.982992+00:00 app[web.1]: from database import
> db_session, init_db 2022-05-28T16:40:10.983010+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
> 2022-05-28T16:40:11.170010+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2022-05-28T16:40:12.093354+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed 2022-05-28T16:40:13.396396+00:00
> heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
> path="/favicon.ico" host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=9dc5d665-f580-4ed2-ac0b-c7ee39b30273 fwd="109.159.28.147"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-05-28T16:40:13.613558+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
> host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=af0d1842-7018-436c-aaa1-d720903dddf0 fwd="109.159.28.147"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-05-28T16:40:13.844478+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
> host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=6990bc7f-b855-4a15-b2ab-dcd022947366 fwd="109.159.28.147"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-05-28T16:56:16.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user
> manuperezroomeroo@gmail.com 2022-05-28T16:56:29.484551+00:00
> heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
> path="/" host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=cb1628f7-f0e0-4078-949a-3875e70c4204 fwd="109.159.28.147"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-05-28T16:56:29.737094+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
> host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=5e9c8628-678a-457f-9887-5afabca2de81 fwd="109.159.28.147"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-05-28T16:57:07.243969+00:00 app[api]: Release v56 created by user
> manuperezroomeroo@gmail.com 2022-05-28T16:57:07.243969+00:00 app[api]:
> Deploy b80c3e1f by user manuperezroomeroo@gmail.com
> 2022-05-28T16:57:08.599436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> crashed to starting 2022-05-28T16:57:12.106230+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
> Starting process with command `python app.py`
> 2022-05-28T16:57:13.113925+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last): 2022-05-28T16:57:13.113939+00:00 app[web.1]: File
> "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module> 2022-05-28T16:57:13.114007+00:00
> app[web.1]: from database import db_session, init_db
> 2022-05-28T16:57:13.114030+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'database' 2022-05-28T16:57:13.259282+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
> 2022-05-28T16:57:13.405036+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> starting to crashed 2022-05-28T16:57:13.411083+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
> State changed from crashed to starting
> 2022-05-28T16:57:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
> 2022-05-28T16:57:17.054039+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `python app.py` 2022-05-28T16:57:18.609227+00:00 app[web.1]:
> Traceback (most recent call last): 2022-05-28T16:57:18.609247+00:00
> app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
> 2022-05-28T16:57:18.609311+00:00 app[web.1]: from database import
> db_session, init_db 2022-05-28T16:57:18.609332+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
> 2022-05-28T16:57:18.743384+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2022-05-28T16:57:18.836107+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed 2022-05-28T16:57:30.348687+00:00
> heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
> path="/" host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=7cddbdca-e8c4-479c-af46-73740e819171 fwd="109.159.28.147"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-05-28T16:57:30.529232+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
> host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=77c5dfe4-957b-43e7-906c-cbc75ac2ea59 fwd="109.159.28.147"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-05-28T17:22:39.666012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
> host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=0efca7cb-4089-463d-a87c-08e4bc100267 fwd="109.159.28.147"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-05-28T17:22:39.887512+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
> host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=8f3930e7-e6d3-4351-9412-a261f4c77c93 fwd="109.159.28.147"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-05-28T17:23:16.580849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
> host=myrecipes-notebook.herokuapp.com
> request_id=ae76349e-e5ad-4267-9e9c-c5f201e48491 fwd="54.152.255.186"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

This is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z327C.png) of the file structure on how I am calling the database module in the `app.py` file.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. it seems you have not sent the `database.py` file to Heroku, login in to the Heroku shell and see the file is there using the `ls` command. Make sure you have pushed your changes to `Heroku master` using `git push heroku master`

Comment: Hi Thanks, @ShivaGaire I run the command: `Heroku run ls` and the `database.py` isn't there.

However, I did git add, commit, and push to GitHub all files and then I did a Heroku push main.

The `database.py` is in the `.gitignore`, it can be something related to that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your error log still clearly says `ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'database' `,   can you verify the content of `database.py`?

Comment: Run `heroku run bash` and then do `ls`. add the file `databse.py` to git and push it to `heroku`. I think it will solve that :)